# Can the screen size of an X11 window be set higher than the monitor's resolution and the view panned around the larger display?

Tags: display, resolution, display-settings, x, viewport

My laptop has screen resolution of 1366x768 but I want to create an X display with a higher resolution and scroll around it.

It was possible in Windows where the drivers and the graphics card allowed it.

Can the same be done in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Assuming that the screen of your laptop is `LVDS-1` (get the real name with `xrandr | grep -w connected`):

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --panning 2732x1536
```

But simple application windows can be larger than the root window or the screen even without that. You can check with

```
xclock -geometry 2732x1536
```

if `xclock(1)` is installed and the window manager doesn't get in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are two ways to do that:

- Create a *window* that is larger than the X framebuffer, and move around the windows origin with help of the window manager (or otherwise, for example directly in the application).
- Create an X *framebuffer* that is larger than the resolution of your monitor, and have X display a *viewport* into the framebuffer with the monitor's resolution, and then move around the viewport. There can be multiple viewports for multiple monitors (e.g. using `xrandr`). You can also make the initial setup permanent with a custom `xorg.conf`.

You can also combine those methods.

(Note that the question asks if it can be done, not about details how to do it, and in particular it doesn't specify a method).